# Nvidia x Server Settings missing scaling options?

Tags: nvidia, scaling

I'm trying to use a 4:3 resolution on a 16:9 screen due to my monitor supporting higher refresh rates in 4:3 resolutions. When I set a 4:3 resolution the screen scales the image to fit a 16:9 aspect ratio. I wanted to disable this and put black bars on my screen but there are no such options in the Nvidia x Server Settings. This option is in windows, so it would suck if it's not in Ubuntu. Can anyone help?